# How do I target middleware at a specific path but not its sub-paths?

Tags: javascript, express

```
app.use('/foo/', myMiddleware, index);
app.use('/foo/image.svg', image);
app.use('/foo/other-page/', otherPage);
```

I have only set `myMiddleware` on the `/foo/` route.

But Express runs `myMiddleware` on **all** the above routes (presumably because the others are sub-paths of the first one).

How do I configure it so `myMiddleware` will **only** work on the `/foo/` route?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer, answering my own question.

If you use `.get()` instead of `.use()` this ensures middleware only works on the specified route.